# Process meshes that have multiple users only once in script

Tags: python

I would like to subdivide all edges of the selected objects. This is what I've done so far:

```
def execute(self, context):
    theScene = bpy.context.scene

    # Store selected objects
    theSelected = bpy.context.selected_objects
    theObjects = set([obj for obj in theSelected if obj.type == 'MESH'])

    # Iterate over selected objects
    for obj in theObjects:
        # Set this object as active
        theScene.objects.active = obj

        # Select all edges in edit mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')

        # Subdivide
        bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide()

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

How to adjust this operator to process meshes only once when they are used in multiple objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array to check if a mesh has been already modified.

```
theScene = bpy.context.scene

# Store selected objects
theSelected = bpy.context.selected_objects
theObjects = set([obj for obj in theSelected if obj.type == 'MESH'])

#all the meshes here:
meshes = []


# Iterate over selected objects
for obj in theObjects:
    # Set this object as active
    theScene.objects.active = obj
    mesh = obj.data

    # Do something if the mesh isn't in the array yet
    if (not mesh in meshes):
        meshes.append(mesh)

        # Select all edges in edit mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')

        print(meshes)

        # Subdivide
        bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide()

        # Toggle Object Mode to select next object
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: That's a good method, thanks. I see that you reset the mode to OBJECT before the next iteration, is this mandatory?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I've added it just because I've got an error while running the script :)

Answer (score 0):

I think names are unique for each data type in a scene, so use those. Either that `set` should be a `dict` with names of meshes as keys, or collect the names of processed meshes into a separate `set` and process only if the name is not in that `set`. You get the mesh name from `obj.data.name`.